# Amazon Product Availability

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, e-commerce, amazon-product-api

Many products on amazon are unavailable but a date is given for when they'll be in stock. I've used AWS and got an XML reply but I can't find the date information anywhere. Is it possible to get this information? Thanks.

NOTE: This is what i've got as a request, what should I alter?

```
http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=MYID&AssociateTag=MYTAG&ItemId=THEITEMID&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Large&ReviewSort=-HelpfulVotes&Service=AWSECommerceService&Signature=MYSIGNATURE&Timestamp=2009-12-04T17%3A35%3A43Z&Version=2009-06-01
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want either PublicationDate or ReleaseDate.  You need to be sure that you're requesting a ResponseGroup that has this data in it.  ItemAttributes has both, but there may be other groups that include them also.

[Amazon Response Elements](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-10-01/DG/index.html?CHAP_response_elements.html)

Comment: What response group should it be?

Comment: as I mentioned, the "ItemAttributes" group has both elements

Comment: ItemAttributes seem to have far less information then what I already use, which is the responsegroup "Large".

Comment: Do you think its because of the type of product? Have you ever had a response that gives you the date at which a products going to be back in stock?

Comment: this is probably a question better asked at the AWS dev forums

http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/forumindex.jspa